# Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host error with htc one m8

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I currently am using a HTC One M8 to debug my app, but as of now it constantly disconnects and connects to adb, eventually going offline. I've tried killing and starting the adb server but that hasn't made a difference. This is all that happens.

```
    10:48:10 AM Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
10:48:11 AM Connection attempts: 1
10:48:14 AM Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
10:48:15 AM Connection attempts: 1
10:48:17 AM Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
10:48:18 AM Connection attempts: 1
```

Comment: Try to test another cable and use rear USB if possible...

Comment: This is happening on my laptop which has Android Studio. I tried using all USB ports on it and it still happens. II could try to use another cable though.

Comment: Try to, unplug device, "adb kill-server" , "adb kill-server" (must run twice), "adb devices" and then, re-connect the device..

Comment: @GuilhermeP I tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: I think I was able to solve it. I had four "adb.exe" files on my laptop. Has to rename the ones that weren't being used, or else they would cause this conflict.